# For WPF which MVVM framework is good?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

1. Prism
2. Cinch
3. MVVM Light

From the above which one you people will suggest?. Is there any good framework available which is more flexible when compare to this?. (Right now i am concentrating on WPF projects and later i will move to Silverlight). At that stage will it easy to convert from one framework to another or we have to do the same thing from the scratch?

Comment: Replaced term pattern with framework. MMVM is a pattern, Prism is a framework i.e. an implementation of the MVVM pattern.

Comment: sorry it was a typo thnx for the correction

Comment: possible duplicate of [What MVVM framework are you using?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280462/what-mvvm-framework-are-you-using)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to try them out yourself to make an informed decision. I personally like MVVM Light and it does have Silverlight support. Obviously you will also be interested in the framework staying around / gaining mind/market share so your investment (in time and research) won't go away.

This podcast might be interesting with you on the topic:

[Hanselminutes Podcast 241 - The MVVM Pattern with Laurent Bugnion](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HanselminutesPodcast241TheMVVMPatternWithLaurentBugnion.aspx)

They are covering MVVM fundamentals and two specific frameworks - MVVM Light and [Caliburn](http://caliburn.codeplex.com/), another MVVM framework that is not on your list yet.

Answer (score 1):

MVVM is the pattern.  Prism, MVVM Light and Cinch aren't patterns, they're frameworks that help you to implement the MVVM pattern.

I've experience MVVM Light and it's fine for what I need but I believe Prism is more feature rich but requires more work to implement?

Answer (score 1):

my view is keep it simple, and just use the WPF teams MVVM toolkit
http://wpf.codeplex.com/releases/view/14962

Comment: whew, you are brave.  Microsoft's 1.0 products are notoriously buggy, I'd hate to imagine a 0.1 product

Comment: You're right :), but its just a visual studio template, with a few code samples to get you going - nothing serious